# how to convert ai to cdr for linux

Tags: linux, command-line, coreldraw

I need ai or eps files to cdr file command line converter.

Comment: what are you exactly trying accomplish? convert ai/eps to coreldraw files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is very good.  Specifically the [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) program.

Just type:

```
convert myimage.ai myimage.cdr
convert myimage.eps myimage.cdr
```

to convert either an .eps or an .ai to a .cdr

Comment: I can't find any confirmation that ImageMagick supports CDR? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: I can't find this either.... I'm sure I tested it when I posed this answer, but I can't find evidence that it does...

Comment: According to [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=9564&start=0), this is somehow possible in IM using Uniconvertor as a delegate program (http://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/) in recent versions of IM.